# I have an old drum machine with a dead 2032 button battery. Can I connect a new battery in parallel with the old and leave the old in place?

Tags: batteries

Old 2032 battery soldered to circuit board.can a connect a new 2032 in parallel and leave the old soldered to the board?

Answer (score 3):

No. The voltage of the old battery is lower than that of the new one, which means that the new battery would attempt to recharge the old one. This means that the old battery will get damaged and can leak or burst. It also means that the old battery will discharge the new one. As a result, if you do just hook the new battery in parallel to the old one, it'll be drained in almost no time.

In short: You have to remove the old one.

Note that the energy flowing from the new battery into the old one will not just charge the old one up again. Those batteries are non-rechargeable, which means that they can't properly hold a charge that was pushed into them externally (if they could, they'd be rechargeable after all). The energy that's pushed into the old battery will instead just damage it and get turned into heat, wasting all the energy from the new battery.